# What is config.msi.exe doing on my computer?

Tags: windows-vista

Found a weird looking folder, but it's not a folder, it's an application (exe) called `Config.msi.exe`.

I cannot open it. When I copy and paste text from an assignment to Notepad or Word, this weird text appears:

> "***TE BWAKA NI BOO***TE BWAKA NI BOO***
>   TE IKA TE ATIBURU,
>   TE KUAU kiokio AO AI TE WII KIOKIO*****
>   AM SPONSOR AIKA TAAN MWAKETE AKE IAAN TE ITAI"

I have no idea where it came from. I know I did not copy that text piece from any source. But now it's stuck there and I can't get rid of it.

What is it and what can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Have you ran a virus scan? Most google searches are showing it as either a virus or malware. Or it could be http://www.pchell.com/support/configmsifolder.shtml

Comment: You've been hit with malware: http://www.prevx.com/filenames/X1646523615076091026-X1/CONFIG.MSI.EXE.html

Comment: If anyone is interested, it is written in Maori, but I can't find a translator anywhere..

Answer (score 1):

This is a virus - [W32/Mokaksu](http://vil.nai.com/vil/content/v_153609.htm) according to McAfee, but I found references to it as the [FUVirus](http://gladiator-antivirus.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=80635) and "save.exe" too.  There is probably 1 infected file in every directory on your computer.  It has been around for some time, so if  you have up-to-date virus scanning software, it should be capable of quarantining and removing it.

If you don't, then I would suggest [HiJackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) - a good, & thorough, but potentially dangerous tool, and [SuperAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/).  You'll want to do a full system scan.

You might also want to check to see if that file has copied itself [under other names on your system](http://www.prevx.com/filenames/X1646523615076091026-X1/CONFIG.MSI.EXE.html).